# Tom Paris chatting up female shuttle pilot in first episode of Voyager

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the first episode of Star Trek:Voyager near the beginning Tom Paris is in a shuttle and is chatting up the pilot. She says "Do you always fly at women at warp speed, Mr. Paris?"
He replies "Only when they're in visual range."

However in streaming versions of this episode on YouTube and Paramount plus this scene has been cut.

I'd like to know when was this scene cut and why. Is it on the DVDs?

This scene is described on Memory Alpha's description of this episode so I'm not just imagining it.
https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Caretaker_(episode)#Act_One

Comment: Are there any other scenes in Star Trek that were originally there but have later been cut?

Comment: Why would they remove that? It's there purely to a.) establish a part of Tom Paris' personality, and b.) show Voyager for the first time. Did they also remove that part of that scene? To answer the question though, that scene is definitely on the DVD release, at least the original one.

Comment: Can you link the Memory Alpha description as well as the date that it was added?

Comment: @Derek they are still seen approaching voyager but most of the dialogue has been cut.

Comment: I just checked Caretaker on Netflix (Canada) and the full scene including the "fly at woman at warp speed" line is still present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory alpha page has a section titled "subsequent edits" which explains scenes were cut as part of converting episode into two parts for syndication.

Comment: Should be noted that streaming services typically end up with the syndicated version, rather than the original broadcast or DVD versions